Incrementally copy new files by LastModifiedDate with Azure Data Factory
[enter image description here] (https://i.sstatic.net/MBwbT11p.png)
"I need to copy files under the condition that only the files that were last modified are copied. Since I have a total of 6 incremental files, I want to copy the files that have changed/been modified to the target file share."

What is the directory structure of source files? and what is the target?

Also, what is your blocker in the above pipeline design? Is it giving any error?

What is the source and target? a storage acccount? or on-prem?

Initially, after running the debug and setting the trigger, the system worked normally. However, over time, I checked the files at both the source and destination, and it turned out that the system was not copying the files as intended. It was not incrementally copying by last modify date.

Storage account

Gen2 or Blob storage account?

Azure File Storage

It can be achieved using following steps:
create a new pipeline.
Add a Get Metadata Activity:
Use the Get Metadata activity to get the last modified date of the files in the source file share.
Configure the Get Metadata activity to point to the source file share and select the "Field list" as Last Modified.
Add a ForEach Activity:
Use a ForEach activity to iterate through the list of files obtained from the Get Metadata activity.
Inside the ForEach activity, add a Lookup activity to get the metadata (last modified date) of each file.
Add a Filter Activity:
Use the Filter activity to filter the files that have been modified.
Configure the Filter activity to compare the last modified date of each file with a stored value (e.g., the last pipeline run date).
Add a Copy Data Activity:
Use the Copy Data activity to copy the filtered files to the target file share.
Configure the source and sink datasets accordingly.
Add a Set Variable Activity:
Use a Set Variable activity to update the stored value of the last pipeline run date.

source directory enter image description here

The steps I took involved defining the datasets on the source side, two datasets. enter image description here
target directory enter image description here

Sorry if the message seems disjointed. It's my first-time using Stack Overflow. Thank you!"

You can edit the question to include these details.

Currently, Azure storage event triggers in ADF or other trigger options like Azure functions or logic apps does not support Azure File share.
As a workaround, you can use a Schedule trigger to schedule the pipeline on a regular basis. In every pipeline run, it checks for the files modified or newly created in during the time gap between last pipeline run end time and current pipeline run start time.
For demo, here, I am scheduling the pipeline using schedule trigger on every day.

In the pipeline, with two Binary datasets for source and target, use copy activity Last Modified Start time and End time. In the start time, use ADF expressions to find your suitable range. Here, as I have scheduled with 1 day interval, I have given the Start time as current_time-24 hrs which @adddays(utcnow(),-1). Give @utcnow() to the End time.
Give your source files folder path in the wild card file path like below.

In the sink binary dataset, give the path till your target folder.

Now if you debug the pipeline, this pipeline will copy the files modified in the last 24 hours to the target location.

On every pipeline run, this pipeline run will copy the modified between pipeline runs to the target. You need to change the trigger interval and Start time as per your requirement.
